# When is a Riemannian metric the pullback of the Euclidean metric?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, isometry, pullback

Let $F:M \to (N,\bar{g})$ be a smooth map between two smooth manifolds  $M \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ and $N \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ of dimension 2, with $\bar{g}$ the Euclidean metric. From what I understand, the components of the pullback metric on $M$ by $F$ are given by:

$$
(F^*\bar{g})_{ij} = {\delta}_{kl} \frac{\partial x^k}{\partial u^i} \frac{\partial x^l}{\partial u^j} = \frac{\partial x^k}{\partial u^i}\frac{\partial x^k}{\partial u^j} = (D_ux)^T(D_ux),
$$

where $F$ maps $(u^1,u^2)$ to $(x^1(u^1,u^2), x^2(u^1,u^2))$ and $D_ux$ is the jacobian matrix of $F$. I also understand from Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* (p.332) that if $F$ is a diffeomorphism, then it is a Riemannian isometry between $(M,F^*\bar{g})$ and $(N,\bar{g})$, and I read that such an isometry preserves e.g. lengths and geodesics.

I am wondering under which conditions one can find a map $F$ such that a given Riemannian metric $g$ is the pullback of the Euclidean metric. More precisely, suppose there is a field of symmetric positive-definite matrices $m_{ij}$.
Does the map whose jacobian matrix is given by $D_ux = m_{ij}^{1/2}$ (the exponent is understood to act on the eigenvalues of $m_{ij}$) and such that $(F^*\bar{g})_{ij} = (D_ux)^T(D_ux) = m_{ij}$, always define a smooth manifold $M$ through $F^{-1}(N)$? If it is the case, are the geodesics of $N$ mapped to geodesics of $M$, since $F$ is an isometry?

I have little background in differential geometry except from what I've read in Lee's book, so please feel free to point out any sloppy part in the question.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A metric is flat (diffeomorphic to an euclidean metric) if its Riemann tensor vanishes. In the $2$ dimensional case, it is sufficient to calculate the Ricci curvature, or its scalar curvature $R$ and show that it is $0$.  When the curvature is $0$ you can construct coordinates that give you and Euclidean metric.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What if both $M$ and $N$ are subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ (and thus $F$ is a change of variable)? Are both metrics flat in this case? I feel I'm missing something...

Comment: If the manifold $N$ "inherits" the Euclidean metric $e =\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}$ from $\mathbb{R}^2$ (of which $N$ is a subset), then it is flat. If we have map  $F:M \to (N,e)$ which is a local diffeomorphism,then the pullback metric induced on $M$ is also flat. There are two ways to characterize flatness of a metric $g$:
1) The existence of local maps (or coordinates) under which $g$ is the pullback of the euclidean metric
2) The vanishing of its associated Riemann Tensor.
 
Their equivalence is proved in theorem 7.10 of "Introduction to Riemann Manifolds" by Lee.